# What is the purpose of using autoWebview capability in Appium especially for iOS (with webviews)?

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

I'm automating an iOS app which is a mix of native and webview part, the problem is whenever I'm switching from native part to webview part I have to do a manual context switch from native to webview using driver.set_context("WEB_VIEW1"). Currently appium is creating problem if we I'm setting autoWebview to true.
My question is does autowebview handle the manual context switch part in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing Hybrid Apps, which are basically 100% webview, it can be inconvenient to remember to switch to using the Webview Context before every test. Sending the autoWebview capability tells appium to automatically switch to the WEBVIEW_CONTEXT as soon as the test starts. Appium also adds some additional logic for waiting until the webview has loaded, which can be a common source of errors.

You can find more information in the link below:
https://discuss.appium.io/t/what-does-the-autowebview-desired-capability-really-do/69/2

Comment: Thanks for answer but in my case WEBVIEW is like 15-20% in app, on using autoWebview: true, my tests got stuck on first page with following error message "Could not find any webviews yet, refreshing/retrying"

Comment: That’s the correct behaviour.If you set autoWebView as true, automatically the context is set for Webview context while starting the test and the Webview may not be available during the beginning of the test. In your case since it is only 15-20%, we donot want to switch the Webview in the beginning itself. We need to use setContext to manually switch between the views.

Comment: Ohh I didn't know that but I use the same thing in Android like autoWebview as true in android and even in android we have 15-20% webview but it works super smooth in Android without any issue, that thing is confusing hell out of me.